# Clear canvas and all clipping without using save() and restore()

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Is there a way to completely clear the canvas and remove all clipping without using the `save()` and `restore()` method?

The reason I ask is that my script is currently crashing Google Chrome and I suspect it has something to do with the memory requirements of these methods.

Just using the `context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)` method fails to remove the clipping paths I've already set...

Comment: No there is no other way to clear the clip. Nor should save restore crash chrome unless you are not matching save and restores or if you have 100's of nested save restores.

Comment: Thanks @Blindman. I think I discovered it was the `clipping()` that was crashing chrome.